# Looking for an alternative for nested try-except block in python

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

I was making an image resizing program using the `pillow` module in python.

I like to program a perfect error-catching program, so I used many nested try-catch blocks in the program below. It works perfectly but I need to modify the code in less number of sloc and try-except blocks.

Please suggest to me a way not to use many try-except blocks but the program works without a problem (with perfect error catching).

```
def GettingValues():
    try:
        img = im.open(input('Enter image name or path: ')) # give image path if image not in current folder
        try:
            width = int(input('Enter required width: '))
            height = int(input('Enter required height: '))
            try:    
                Resizer(img, width, height)
            except:
                print('Error calling Resizer function. Try Again')            
        except:
            print("Error in Width or Height Values. Try Again")    
    except:
        print("Error in file name. Try Again")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use bare `except` clauses for starters. If you'd catch more specific exceptions, you may be able to distinguish them by their type alone, not by their `try` block. You also don't need to nest these blocks, you can abort the function (e.g. `return`) when an exception occurred, and then proceed with the next `try` block sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single `try` and different `except` clauses (including one for unexpected errors):

```
def GettingValues():
    try:
        img = im.open(input('Enter image name or path: ')) # give image path if image not in current folder
        width = int(input('Enter required width: '))
        height = int(input('Enter required height: '))
        Resizer(img, width, height)
    except ResizerError: print('Error calling Resizer function. Try Again')            
    except ValueError: print("Error in Width or Height Values. Try Again")    
    except OSError: print("Error in file name. Try Again") 
    except Exception: print("Unknown error. Try Again")
```

Note: I'm assuming you defined a `ResizerError` and `Resizer` raises it if something goes wrong

Comment: The last one should be `except Exception`, never a bare `except` block, unless you also want to catch keyboard interrupt exceptions and such (which you typically don't).

Comment: @deceze, good point, I'm editing the answer. Also, I didn't mention one may want to check `sys.exc_info` and give a more informative message

Comment: @gimix, your correction worked perfectly. Thank You... I don't have enough reputation to make the answer as `useful` sorry :(